# How to make nginx ssl customized

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a below code where Im trying to use https ssl. My requirement is to hit the below url `https://server_name:3000`

Below is nginx.conf file.

```
upstream appa_backend {
server server_name:3000;
}

server {
listen               443;
ssl                  on;
#other conf

location /appa/ {
proxy_pass http://appa_backend/;
}
```

How can I run https call with customized port.

Answer (score 0):

So why didn't you set https as the protocol in proxy_pass line? Like:

```
 location /appa/ {
   proxy_pass https://appa_backend/;
 }
```

Another catch would be specifying full path to your upstream:

```
 upstream appa_backend {
   server https://server_name:3000;
 }
```

Then you don't need to specify protocol on proxy_pass line.

Comment: After adding `upstream appa_backend { server https://server_name:3000` }; When i run in chrome `https://server_name:3000` i get error "The web page cannot be displayed"

Comment: Ahem. Is server at server_name:3000 talking https?